# Determining the end time of my procedure

Tags: vba, ms-access, time, format

In my form I have 2 combo boxes and 2 text boxes also 1 temp variable

cboProcedure = Displays the registered procedures
dDuration = This is the temp variable , it will store the duration of the procedure
cboTime = Displays the time of the day, divided by what the the temp variable says(Ex. dDuration = "1:00", cboTime will display in a dropdown menu, 9:00, 10:00, 11:00,12:00)
txtEndTime = The end of the procedure, this is what Im trying to get 
Text101 = This is the text box that displays the actual value of dDuration.(ex 1:00)
I tried to make a code to sum the cboTime.Text(What I chose) + [Text101] = its supposed to give me the End Time of the procedure, but All I get is "8:55 AM+0:55". This is what I tried.

```
    Format(Me.cboTime, "h:nn AM/PM") & "+" & Format([Text101], "h:nn AM/PM")
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to sum time values...is this possible?

Comment: With respect I've read this six times now and I still don't understand what you want. Could you re-phrase the question? Be specific and assume no one knows what your form looks like. What is it you want to do?

Comment: ok I Got a Form with cboTime, [Text101] and [txtEndTime], I just want to be able to sum the text box of cboTime and the time value that is stored in [Text101] and the end result will be presented in [txtEndTime], like if cboTime.text is (9:00) and my duration is (0:10) then the end result will be 9:10

Comment: The "#####" might be the result of spreadsheet columns too narrow --- make your columns wider. Maybe could happen if cboTime or Text101 has invalid data. Also, to get the end time you should do the sum **before** formatting: `Format(Me.cboTime + [Text101], "h:nn AM/PM")`

Comment: Ok I made that text box bigger and it showed me only the equation "8:55 AM+0:55" without doing the operation... I want it to sum those values and display the end value, like "9:50 AM"

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved it, I had to do some more extra stuff to tell the program 9:00 AM + 0:55 = 9:55 AM... here's what I did:
    Dim d, e, m, l As Date

```
    d = Format([Text101], "n")
    m = Format(Me.txtAppointDate, "Long Date")
    l = Format([cboTime], "h:nn")
    e = DateAdd("n", d, l)
    Me.txtEndTime = Format(e, "h:nn AMPM")
```

'I needed to make this equation get the value of the duration time of a procedure depending on cboProcedure, so I built a select case:

```
 Select Case Me.cboProcedure
Case "Haircut"
dDuration = TimeValue([Text101])
    d = Format([Text101], "n")
    m = Format(Me.txtAppointDate, "Long Date")
    l = Format([cboTime], "h:nn")
    e = DateAdd("n", d, l)
    Me.txtEndTime = Format(e, "h:nn AMPM")
 Case "Hair Coloring"
 dDuration = TimeValue([Text107])
    d = Format([Text107], "n")
    m = Format(Me.txtAppointDate, "Long Date")
    l = Format([cboTime], "h:nn")
    e = DateAdd("n", d, l)
    Me.txtEndTime = Format(e, "h:nn AMPM")
Case "Eyebrows Making"
dDuration = TimeValue([Text109])
    d = Format([Text109], "n")
    m = Format(Me.txtAppointDate, "Long Date")
    l = Format([cboTime], "h:nn")
    e = DateAdd("n", d, l)
    Me.txtEndTime = Format(e, "h:nn AMPM")
Case "Other"
dDuration = TimeValue([Text111])
    d = Format([Text111], "n")
    m = Format(Me.txtAppointDate, "Long Date")
    l = Format([cboTime], "h:nn")
    e = DateAdd("n", d, l)
    Me.txtEndTime = Format(e, "h:nn AMPM")
End Select
```

now depending on a procedure my duration time will cost, so if the procedure is "X" then do this math